# Precision of $\sinh x$ at $x \approx 0$

Tags: numerical-methods

What can we do to increase the precision of $\sinh x$ at $x \approx 0$?

I tried to use conjugation , but it gives me $e^{2x} - e^{-2x}$ which is again the subtraction of "similar" numbers at $x \approx 0$

Thank you

Comment: Have you found some problem with the $\sinh$ function provided by your computer/OS/language? I guarantee that the guys who wrote that function have a lot more expertise in this area than you or I. So, unless you have some very special needs, I would be inclined to just trust them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unlikely that $\sinh x$ is computed using the definition when $x\approx 0$, exactly to avoid subtraction cancellation.

Indeed, when $x\approx 0$ one uses the Taylor expansion
$
\sinh x \approx x+x^3/6+x^5/120+O(x^7)
$
or a better polynomial or rational function (Padé approximant), as for instance in http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~svb/CS/Lab/Minix%203/lib/math/sinh.c.